# Prevent hotlinking to files using hashes?

Tags: php, html, security

I am looking to have my files on my PHP site like so

http://mysite.com/files/file.exe?auth=qwe1245efmkrkn%$!e12 <-- some generated hash...

I haven't written any code, but I was wondering how I would implement the auth variable for a direct link to a file.. any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, better with `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Copy and paste this code, rename it with `.htaccess` and save on the root.

As Gumbo mentioned, its true that some browsers, do not send any request header and forging a request is very easy, unless you apply CSRF protection on your website. 
So an updated .htaccess to allow this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain\.com/ [NC]
#Redirect to an image
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink\.(gif|png) [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|jpg|png)$ http://yourdomain.com/images/hotlink.png [NC]
```

and adding

```
Header set X-Frame-Options DENY
```

ensures the website from being framed, even from the same website. Might be a little helpful against CSRF.

Alternative to this, might be redirecting an image request to a page to handle it.

Comment: thanks for your input! are you saying that there won't be any way to do what I want up there?

Comment: @user987103, actually I answered based on the title, your question does not make any sense. It would be better if you change it to make it a little bit more understandable.

Comment: -1 Two reasons: First, some user agents don’t send an HTTP referrer, and second, forging a request with an HTTP referrer is quite easy.

Comment: @Gumbo, that's the best I can give. Please input if you have additional solutions

Answer (score 2):

you would need to hash the the path using an expiration, passed as part of the link,

HASH = the path + secret + expiration

link looks like ?hash=[resulting hash]&expiration=192009345 <-- time link expires in milliseconds since unix epoc.

Then when serving the file you would hash using your secret + path + experation you get from inbound link, if hashes match and expiration has not passed, serve the file if not throw a 403

You can rewrite assets through the htaccess to use your hashing script and keep actual assets in a non-public folder and then serve them through the php script using headers for content type and dumping the binary out in a file read operation.

note: never put your secret in the link that is only on your server side code

Something like below:

`RewriteEngine on`

`RewriteRule \(.*)(\.jpg|\.gif|\.png)$ hashChecker.php?file=$1$2 [QSA]`

Comment: thanks! that is exactly what I was needing to hear .. how would I make htaccess use the scripts?

Comment: Updated with something that could work, it depends how you are setup. THeres tons of guides, check mod_rewrite in google

Comment: so far i have what you put up top in my htaccess file. In the .php file in the htaccess file i just have it output what the variable file equals using $_GET['file'] -- all it shows is 'exe', is there a way i can see the whole variable passed?

Comment: oops yeah thats because of me using the capture group like that... im not a regex ninja